# .net core/Windows Authentication

Tags: .net-core, dnx50

I'm writing my first application using .net core (asp.net 5) and Windows Authentication. I would like to access the the current user in my Repository.

In the Startup.cs class, can I use dependency injection to pass current user to repository?
Currently, I have I use "services.AddScoped()" in the startup.cs class to use a repository.

Comment: You can create a Windows Authentication app by changing the authentication type when you are creating your project.  You do not need to setup any middleware `(AddScoped)`.  Click the `Change Authentication` button when you select the project template.  Try that first and then see if you have what you need.

Comment: I have done that. However, HttpContextl and User is null in the Controller when using IIS.{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1234/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },

Comment: @Kiran, did you sort out problem on local IIS server. I also cant get it to work?

Comment: @Kiran I'm getting the same thing. I create the template for a .Net Core 2.0 and 2.1 with Windows Authentication and when I run in Visual Studio it works. When I publish to IIS the User is empty. Doesn't work. Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS. It used to work but now it does not.